# How to retrieve user name in realm

Tags: java, realm, realm-mobile-platform

```
SyncUser user = SyncUser.currentUser();
String identity = user.getIdentity();
String username = ?
```

I can retrieve id of user but how to get username?

Comment: Please refer this link https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/SyncUser.html , They have used 'identity' to find the user.

Comment: I can't put extra info to SyncUser, thats why I want to put extra info data to another RealmObject for ex: UserInfo, I need to get the username from SyncUser and put it to UserInfo to show in UI later by getting username from it.

Comment: There's an issue tracking this https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4645 you will be able to use `SyncUser` profile values, to store a different kind of key-value properties. There's a PR in progress https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/4790

Answer (score 1):

`username` is specific to a certain type of login (using `SyncCredentials.usernamePassword`), this is why `SyncUser` is agnostic to this information and work only with the user identity (another type of login may use a Facebook/Google token so no username here)

It’s the user responsibility to keep the `SyncCredentials` instance used to create the user, you can then retrieve it using `SyncCredentials.getUserIdentifier()`.

eg.:

```
// store this somewhere
static SyncCredentials creds = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword("foo", "bar", true);

SyncUser.login(creds, AUTH_URL);

String username = creds.getUserIdentifier(); // "foo"
```

Also, check https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4645 and https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4790 for more information.